# Pymc3 Type Error __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'coords'

Tags: python, pymc3

I'm using pymc3 to set up a mixed effects model using the attribute coords to assign individual intercept values to each of a list of test subjects (Chimp) and also to a list of treatments (Treatment).  I got the code from a university class that I'm taking so I know for a fact that it works for my professor (who uses a mac, whereas I'm a pc).  Not working for me despite having updated pymc3 in conda.  Can't find any similar error postings. Help!

code:

```
with pm.Model(coords={'Chimp':Chimp, 'Treat': Treatment}) as Chimps:

    # Individual intercepts
    β0 = pm.Normal('Actor', 0, 1.7, dims='Chimp')
    # Treatment effects
    β1 = pm.Normal('Treatment', 0, 0.25, dims='Treat')

    # Linear model
    p = pm.invlogit(β0[Ia]+β1[It])

    # Likelihood
    Yi = pm.Binomial('Yi', 1, p,observed=L)
```

Treatment looks like this: ['R/N', 'L/N', 'R/P', 'L/P']
Chimp looks like this:  ['Chimp 1', 'Chimp 2', 'Chimp 3', 'Chimp 4', 'Chimp 5', 'Chimp 6', 'Chimp 7']

Full error message looks like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-a4c6b628083c> in <module>
----> 1 with pm.Model(coords={'Chimp':Chimp, 'Treat': Treatment}) as Chimps:
      2   # Use coords to connect the individual treatment/chimp names to the different intercepts
      3 
      4     # Individual intercepts
      5     # mixed effect model? every chimp gets their own intercept

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymc3\model.py in __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    274         instance = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
    275         with instance:  # appends context
--> 276             instance.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    277         return instance
    278 

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'coords'
```

Comment: This is most likely a pymc3 version problem. You got a code written for v3.9 but conda is using v3.8 I believe. Not sure why conda didn't update it to v3.9 you may have to install pymc3 using pip.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. For some reason simply updating pymc3 in conda didn't do the trick, but then I updated pymc3 and specified the version number I wanted (3.9).